# fnding boundries of browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way to find boundary of browser

actually I am showing a div popup. It's working fine but it not showing properly when it comes at boundaries.

so i want to change position of div at boundary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` hold the physical dimensions of viewable space. You can then use the `left`, `top`, `width` and `height` CSS properties to see if an element is inside this boundary.